# Cucumber tests not running using ant?

Tags: java, testing, ant, cucumber, build.xml

I am deploying cucumber tests using ant. Ant generates reports however the status of these tests are skipped and the scenario says it is undefined.
I am wondering is it an issue with my runner class?

My code:

```
package cucumber;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(,
        plugin = {"html:target/cucumber-html-report","junit:target/cucumber-junit-report/test.xml"},
        features = {"src/cucumber/features"} )
public class CucumberRunner {

}
```

My build.xml

```
<!-- Build targets -->
<target name="build" description="Build project" depends="clean,compile,package"/>
<target name="test" description="Test project" depends="build">
        <mkdir dir="target/cucumber-junit-report"/>
        <java classname="cucumber.api.cli.Main" fork="true" failonerror="false" resultproperty="cucumber.exitstatus">
            <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
            <arg value="--format"/>
            <!-- creates our junit report -->
            <arg value="junit:target/cucumber-junit-report/test.xml"/>
            <arg value="--format"/>
            <arg value="pretty"/>
            <arg value="--format"/>
            <!-- creates our cucumber html friendly report -->
            <arg value="html:target/cucumber-html-report"/>
            <arg value="--format"/>
            <!-- creates our cucumber json friendly report -->
            <arg value="json:target/cucumber.json"/>
            <arg value="--glue"/>
            <!-- identifies the package (folder) where the cucumber definitions live -->
            <arg value="test.src.cucumber.features"/>
            <!-- identifies the folder where the feature files live (looks in all subfolders) -->
            <arg value="test/src/cucumber"/>
        </java>

        <!-- writes out information to junit report -->
        <junitreport todir="target/cucumber-junit-report">
            <fileset dir="target/cucumber-junit-report">
                <include name="test.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="target/cucumber-junit-report"/>
        </junitreport>

        <!-- checks our exit status, and determines success or failure -->
        <fail message="Cucumber failed">
            <condition>
                <not>
                    <equals arg1="${cucumber.exitstatus}" arg2="0"/>
                </not>
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at you runner class doesn't tell me that it is broken.

I would, however, reduce the problem and start with something that worked. In this case, I would clone https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton or download it as a zip and see that it worked. I would then introduce the things you have step by step. Very small steps and always verify that the scenarios are executed properly.

You have some kind of issue and you have, at least in my opinion, a lot of things going on in your build.

Remember Gall's law:
"A complex system that works is invariably found to have evolved from a simple system that worked. A complex system designed from scratch never works and cannot be patched up to make it work. You have to start over with a working simple system."

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to extend an abstract test class similar to this

```
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
```